# Sorting SQL query after search result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, t-sql, search

I have table that contains column FULL_NAME, and I'm doing search and getting result. I need to sort these columns by position of search(search term).

```
Example Of data
Column (FULL_NAME)
```

| ID | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | zaid said Alabri |
| 2 | said sleem salim AlAhmedi |
| 3 | salim zaid Ahmed AlZaid |
| 4 | Ahmed said zaid AlSalimi |

Search example:

```
SELECT FULL_NAME
FROM Table
WHERE(FULL_NAME LIKE N'%ِAhmed%')
```

I need result to be like this

| ID | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **Ahmed** said zaid AlSalimi |
| 2 | said **Ahmed** salim AlAhmedi |
| 3 | salim zaid **Ahmed** AlZaid |
| 4 | said sleem salim **AlAhmedi** |

This what I'm seeking result sort by position after query result.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: BTW, do you mean character position, or word position?

Comment: MSSQL -WORD POSITION ty:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think if you are using SQL server you can use a conditional order by and using CHARIndex
as follow

```
SELECT    EnglishName   
FROM            Employees
where EnglishName like N'%Ahmed%' 
order by charindex(N'Ahmed',EnglishName,1)
```

Comment: condition for case = true

Comment: Ahmed kindly remove the condition also it will work

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged SQL Server as your database please try this:

```
select *
from table
where full_name like N'%Ahmed%'
order by charindex('Ahmed',full_name,1)
```

Comment: i tried but not in right position ,thank u for ur answer

Comment: @NicedMoral What's wrong with this answer?

Comment: @Charlieface its doesn't work before u changed u replay as samir solution XD

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for you:

```
select *
from table
where full_name like N'%Ahmed%'
order by charindex(N'Ahmed', full_name)
```

The `charindex` function returns the character number where the search matches a string.

Comment: changed for sql server